# How do you view the active Conda environment in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I have 3 Conda environments set up (in addition to the base environment).
[image: anaconda navigator environment list]

In VSCode you can easily select a Conda environment as your Python interpreter.
[image: vscode python interpreter list]

Great!
But the name shown isn't specific to the environment, just the interpreter.

[image: status bar name]

How do you get this to show something like
`Anaconda Python 3.7.0 [environment-2]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the exact date it happened but this feature is now launched.

[image: conda in vscode python]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the fact that when you installed Anaconda you left it off of your `PATH`. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2266).

Comment: I don't think the question was clear enough. I don't mean the auto-detection of the environment, I mean the display name of the selected environment. The question has been updated for clarity.

Comment: I believe we already have a PR in that updates how we display environment details that will address the environment name.